# Using Assert() in a C++ test project for "test project" bugs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

Is it appropriate to use the Assert() function in a Visual Studio C++ test project for bugs WITHIN the test project? The Visual Studio test projects for C++ use
namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework

For instance, I have a function that builds a vector full of random char value strings, how should I handle the case in which the user of the class uses it with the wrong arguments? Would it be appropriate to add a Assert::IsTrue(myVec.size() > 0) and then have the possibility of the test project it's self cause a test to fail?

An example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a vector of std::string with randomized content.
    /// count is the number of entries in the returned vector, length is the max length of the strings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> a vector of std::string with randomized content. Empty vector on error. </returns>
    std::vector<std::string> BuildRandomStringVector(const int count, const int length, const int minLength = 3)
    {
        //arg error checking, returns empty vector as per description
        if (minLength >= length || (length <= 0) || (count <=0) || (minLength <=0))
        {
            return std::vector<std::string>();
        }

        //Test all kinds of random character possibilities.
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distCharPossibility
        (std::numeric_limits<char>::min(), 
            std::numeric_limits<char>::max());

        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distLengthPossibility(minLength, length);

        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 stringGenerator(rd());
        std::vector<std::string> ret;

        //the distribution uses the generator engine to get the value
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            const int tLength = distLengthPossibility(stringGenerator);
            std::string currentBuiltString = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < tLength; j++)
            {
                char currentBuiltChar = distCharPossibility(stringGenerator);
                currentBuiltString += currentBuiltChar;
            }
            ret.push_back(currentBuiltString);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: there is no `Assert` in the example?

Comment: apple, pretend there is "Assert::IsTrue(minLength >= length);" etc. in the error checking at the top of the function instead of returning an empty vector. But for that matter the Assert could be anywhere in the test project, the question is should the test project code cause a test failure for the project being tested?

Comment: @ woofdiggy there is nothing wrong to add the Assert, they just have different semantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not reccommend using any form of assertions in tests. The rationale is as follows. Assertion is a diagnostic code that is normally executed in "Debug" mode and skipped in "Release". You don't intend to run tests in two different modes, do  you? And you are not going to test tests. Verification of the condition in your code should not have any measurable impact on the test execution time. In such a case prefer reliability: always perform the test sanity, for you can certainly afford a few microseconds longer tests. If violation of the condition should be considered an error, don't return an empty vector: will you be checking its size at the caller each time? Throw an exception. In short, rather then an assertion, use `std::invalid_argument` or something similar. Fire and forget.

From another viewpoint: in principle we could embed a lot of self-testing in production code, but we prefer external tests so that the production code is really slim and fast. This concern is not that important for tests: if you're afraid they can be used improperly, test the correctness of their usage explicitly and unconditionally. Use the common sense to tell when the overhead is still acceptable.

Comment: well test framework assertion probably would not be skipped in release mode. (and probably it's actually implemented with exception)

Comment: @appleapple Yes. For example, GoogleTest has macros like ASSERT_TRUE, ASSERT_EQ etc. They are always evaluated, but they belong to the framework. I think I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @appleapple After a while I came to the conclusion that using test framework assertions is not the best solution. I use macros like `ASSERT_TRUE`  from GTest when the condition tested in it is absolutely necessary for the rest of the test to be "sane". For example, if a vector is empty, it would be an error to call its `front` member function. How to handle the scenario described by OP should  be decided by the developers, but `Assert` will not belong to acceptable solutions.

Comment: not sure where is the difference? OP said he is using `Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework` and [mention `Assert::IsTrue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558232/using-assert-in-a-c-test-project-for-test-project-bugs/69578851?noredirect=1#comment122947745_69558232) which should be a test-framework assertion, same as `ASSERT_TRUE`. it definitely belong to acceptable solutions.